# creating NI labview alarm

Tags: labview

I'm trying to build an application thats asks a patient in the hospital how he or she is feeling, if the patient responds "well" I want to create an alarm that after two hours repeats the same the question, or if that's not possible to turn on a led or an alarm which will alert the patient to register his or her health status (well/unwell).

So far i've used a case structure and a while loop but i'm confused on how to create the alarm/get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

you're going to need to create a state machine to handle this.  I would create the following states:

- init
- prompt patient
- raise alarm
- clear alarm
- idle

the big one is idle, where the time is checked against the last time an alarm was thrown. Here's where you'll need to compare the times and see if they are different by more than 2 hours.

The raise alarm will reset this 'saved time' and store it in a shift register for you.

Here's a suggestion:
Edit your original post with screenshots of what you've got so far. You're not going to get the answers you need because nobody is going to write the code for you.